# extension from a dense subset in completely uniformizable spaces

Tags: uniform-spaces, extension

Let $\mathbf{CReg}$ the category of completely regular spaces and continuous maps and let $\mathbf{Unif}$ be the category of uniform spaces and uniformly continuous maps.

There is a functor $F:\mathbf{CReg}\to \mathbf{Unif}$ that sends a completely regular space that the finest uniformity inducing the topology, the *fine uniformity*. This functor is left adjoint to the forgetful functor $U:\mathbf{Unif}\to \mathbf{CReg}$.

My question is: *What goes wrong in the following argument?*

Let $X$ be a completely regular space and let $Y$ be a completely uniformizable completely regular space. Let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$ and let $f:A\to Y$ be a continuous map.

By applying the functor $F$, we obtain a uniformly continuous function $Ff:FA\to FY$, where $FY$ is a complete uniform space. Since $FA$ is dense in $FX$, there is a unique uniformly continuous extension $g:FX\to FY$. This gives a continuous extension $Ug:X\to Y$ of $f$.

I believe that this result is wrong, but I cannot see where the mistake is.

Comment: The uniformity on $FA$ is not the one induced by $FX$, e.g., in the example $A=(0,1)$ and $X=[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies it for me.